# How can we calculate time to read file in node.js?

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to calculate how much time is spent in reading a file from disk using fs.readFile() in node.js?Following is the code i am using to read-file:

```
const readVideoFromDisc = (videoName, fileName) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.readFile(BASE_FOLDER + "/" + videoName + "/" + fileName, function(
      err,
      buf
    ) {
      // store files in redis buffer
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      }
      console.log("read disc", fileName);
      resolve(buf);
    });
  });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Store the time before to launch, then look at the time when it finishes

```
const readVideoFromDisc = (videoName, fileName) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const startTime = Date.now();

    fs.readFile(BASE_FOLDER + "/" + videoName + "/" + fileName, (
      err,
      buf
    ) => {
      const totalReadingTime = Date.now() - startTime;

      console.log(`Reading the file took ${totalReadingTime}ms`);

      // store files in redis buffer
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      }

      console.log("read disc", fileName);

      resolve(buf);
    });
  });
};
```

---

Also, you could turn your code into :

```
const readVideoFromDisc = async(videoName, fileName) => {
  const startTime = Date.now();

  const buf = util.promisify(fs.readFile)(`${BASE_FOLDER}/${videoName}/${fileName}`);

  const totalReadingTime = Date.now() - startTime;

  console.log(`Reading the file took ${totalReadingTime}ms`);

  console.log("read disc", fileName);

  return buf;
};
```